# I can't type space when my AutoHotKey script is running?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm new to AHK.

I am trying to create a script that is a better version of alt-tab and shift-alt-tab.

So far I have:

```
Space & L::AltTab
Space & K::ShiftAltTab
```

and it works, but when I try to type a space in normal writing, it doesn't work (I have to close the script in task manager).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with **~**

```
~Space & L::AltTab
~Space & K::ShiftAltTab
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [`~`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde) in front of the hotkey so it isn't consumed.

```
~Space & L::AltTab
~Space & K::ShiftAltTab
```